# Placing $4$ numbers on (-1,1) following some conditions!

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to place 4 numbers, call them $A,B,C$ and $D$ on (-1,1) subject to the following conditions:

(1) $A>B>0>C>D$ i.e. $A$ and $B$ are positive (with $A>B$) while $C$ and $D$ are negative (with $C>D$).

(2) $A-B >C-D$

(3) $ A*C > B*D $

On the space of all placements of numbers satisfying condition (1), how many cases (measure), do also satisfy (2) and (3)?

I failed so far to conceptualize the problem better, if you have intuition about the discrete case, please let me know! Your input will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $A+B=1+x$, $A-B=y$. Then the point $(X,Y)$ is distributed according to area measure in the triangle $\{(x,y)\ |\ 0\leq y\leq 1-|x|\}$; see the following figure.

[image]

Similarly, let $(-D)+(-C)=1+u$, $(-D)-(-C)=v$. Then the point $(U,V)$ is equidistributed in the triangle $\{(u,v)\ |\ 0\leq v\leq 1-|u|\}$.

The restriction $(2)$ amounts to $V\leq Y$. The probability that it is fulfilled is obviously ${1\over2}$, on account of symmetry. In the following we condition on  $(Y,V)$, where $0\leq V\leq Y\leq1$. For a given $y\in[0,1]$ the probability that $y\leq Y\leq y+dy$ is given by $2(1-y)\>dy\ $ (= the area of the dark green strip in the above figure). Therefore the a-priori probability density of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=2(1-y)$, and that of $v$ is $f_V(v)=2(1-v)$. It follows that the  joint probability density for $(Y,V)$ is given by
$$f(y,v)=8(1-y)(1-v)\qquad(0\leq v\leq y\leq1)$$
and $=0$ elsewhere.

[image]

For given admissible $Y$ and $V$ the point $(X,U)$ encoding the remaining two coordinates is equidistributed in the rectangle $R_{y,v}:=[-1+y,1-y]\times[-1+v,1-v]$ of the $(x,u)$ plane, see the above figure. The condition $(3)$ amounts to
$$y(1+u)\leq v(1+x)\ ,$$
and defines a triangle $G_{y,v}\subset R_{y,v}$ of "good" points in $R_{y,v}\>$. Computation shows that
$${{\rm area}(G_{y,v})\over {\rm area}(R_{y,v})}={v(1-y)\over2(1-v)y}=:p(y,v)\ .$$
The overall probability $P$ that a given $(1)$-admissible quadruple $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ is good is then given by
$$P={1\over2}\int_0^1\int_0^y p(y,v) f(y,v)\ dv\ dy={1\over12}\ .$$
**Update:** For corroboration I did a simulation with $12\cdot 10^6$ trials satisfying condition $(1)$. I got $1\,000\,718$ good quadruples.

Comment: Prof @Blatter, I reconstructed the proof! A masterpiece, thank you!

Comment: Prof Blatter, I tried to work the whole thing assuming now that condition (1) becomes: A>B>0>E>C>D where E is an independent uniformly distributed random variable on $(0,1)$. Going on your footsteps, I found that $P(V≤Y)=2/5$ and that $f(y,v)=15(1−y)(1−v)^2$ when $0≤v≤y≤1$ and $0$ otherwise. It sounded fine but to continue with the second part, I run into problems, I think because $(x,u)$ are not anymore equidistributed on $\left[y−1,1−y\right]×\left[v−1,1−v\right]$. Any hints? Thousand thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something in the line of: $$\frac{\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^z[x-y>z-u][xz>yu]dudzdydx}{\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^zdudzdydx}$$  where $[x-y>z-u]$ and $[xz>yu]$ denote the characteristic functions on $(-1,1)^4$ related to the conditions.